# How to separate function execution when different buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I am using JQuery's `.click` function and I have multiple buttons on my website. Clicking one button will execute every `.click` function in my HTML document. Is there a way to make one button execute one `.click`? I have included some code below to illustrate my problem. Clicking the first button called "Click Me!" will execute all the functions in my HTML document. How would I make it so that the button "Click Me!" does not execute every function in my document?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <title>
            My Website
        </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
              content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


    </head>
    <body>

        <button>
            Click Me!
        </button>      

        <button onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor='blue';">
            Change BG color
        </button>


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

               $("button").click(function(){
                   $("#d").hide();
               }); 

            });

            $(document).ready(function () {
               $("button").click(function(){
                   $("#f").fadeToggle(3000);
               }); 

            });

        </script>

    <button>Toggle fade</button>


            <div>
            <p id="d">Some text here.</p>
            </div>

        <div>
            <p id="f">Some text to fade.</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

***Update**
So I have changed my script to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

               $('#button1').click(function(){
                   $("#d").hide();
               }); 

            });
```

Nothing happens when I click the button though. Is this the correct syntax? This syntax was used on W3Schools.

Comment: You could give your buttons IDs, and then assign unique event listenrs to them. Your code is selecting all `button` elements, and when one of them is clicked, all the listeners fire.

Comment: Your syntax looks ok in your update but it requires you to have an `id="button1"` attribute on your button. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26554531/361762) which has a runnable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `$("button")`, the `click()` function you provide will apply to ALL buttons. I would recommend giving your button an id and then use:

```
$("#myButtonId").click(function(){
    $("#d").hide();
});
```

JQuery [selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp) are very useful for targeting your elements in the DOM.

Comment: I have done this but nothing happens when I click the button. Does the script have to come before the button in the document?

Comment: Its a good idea to put your script near the top of your document. I would double check that you're referencing the id of the button correctly. I added a link about JQuery selectors for reference.

Comment: It's not necessary in this case to use `$(document).ready` to assign your click function. Your button html is like this: `<button id="button1">Click Me!</button>`   ?

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Put an ID or Class on that button so you can select it with more specificity.

`<button id="button1">foo</button>`
`<button id="button2">bar</button>`

`$('#button1').on('click', function(){ $("#d").hide(); });`
`$('#button2').on('click', function(){ console.log("button2"); });`

Answer (score 0):

You should give the button and ID or class like so:

```
<button id="myButton">Test</button>
```

And then use the following click event:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
 ...
});
```